# What else I can do for maximum power saving on my HP Pavillion 15 laptop? See the TLP-stat

Tags: 16.04, power-management, intel, tlp, governor

--- TLP 0.8 --------------------------------------------

```
+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=performance
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=powersave
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="radeon nouveau"
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0
```

+++ System Info

```
System         = Hewlett-Packard 0992110000004100000600080 HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC
BIOS           = F.68
Release        = Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Kernel         = 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=a09d33ee-ea3f-47fe-b737-a53c1d439c12 ro quiet splash intel_pstate=enable vt.handoff=7
Init system    = systemd
```

+++ System Status

```
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = AC
```

+++ Processor

```
CPU Model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2600000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2600000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2600000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2600000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      = 30
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          = 0

x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = performance

/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0
```

+++ Undervolting

```
PHC kernel not available.
```

+++ Temperatures

```
CPU temp               =    47 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)
```

+++ File System

```
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     0
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    20
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =    10
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/age_buffer_centisecs  = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs    = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfsbufd_centisecs     = (not available)
```

+++ Storage Devices

```
/dev/sda:
          Model     = SanDisk SDSSDA240G                      
          Firmware  = U21010RL
          APM Level = 254
          Status    = active/idle
          TRIM      = supported
          Scheduler = deadline

        SMART info:
            5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct     =        0 
            9 Power_On_Hours            =       37 [h]
          194 Temperature_Celsius       =       37 (Min/Max 0/56)  [°C]
          232 Available_Reservd_Space   =      100 [%]
          233 Media_Wearout_Indicator   =      100 [%]
          241 Total_LBAs_Written        =    0.000 [TB]

/dev/sdb:
          Model     = ST500LT012-9WS142                       
          Firmware  = 0001YAM1
          APM Level = 254
          Status    = active/idle
          Scheduler = deadline

        SMART info:
            4 Start_Stop_Count          =     9326 
            5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct     =        0 
            9 Power_On_Hours            =     6366 [h]
          190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel   =       35 [°C]
          193 Load_Cycle_Count          =    91048 
          194 Temperature_Celsius       =       35 (0 11 0 [°C]
```

+++ SATA Aggressive Link Power Management

```
/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
```

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management

```
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = default (using bios preferences)
```

+++ Intel Graphics

```
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave        = (not available)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_rc6       =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc       = -1 (use per-chip default)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock   = (not available)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores       = -1 (use per-chip default)
```

+++ Wireless

```
bluetooth = none (no device)
wifi      = on
wwan      = none (no device)

wlo1(rt2800pci)     : connected, power management = on
```

+++ Audio

```
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 0
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = N
```

+++ Runtime Power Management

```
device classes   = all
device blacklist = (not configured)
driver blacklist = radeon nouveau

/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = on   (0x060000, Host bridge, hsw_uncore)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = on   (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, i915)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0/power/control = on   (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control = on   (0x078000, Communication controller, mei_me)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control = on   (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.1/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.2/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.4/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0320, USB controller, ehci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = on   (0x060100, ISA bridge, lpc_ich)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = on   (0x010601, SATA controller, ahci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = on   (0x0c0500, SMBus, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/power/control = on   (0x028000, Network controller, rt2800pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.1/power/control = on   (0x0d1100, Bluetooth, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:09:00.0/power/control = on   (0x020000, Ethernet controller, r8169)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0a:00.0/power/control = on   (0x030200, 3D controller, no driver)
```

+++ USB

```
autosuspend        = enabled
device whitelist   = (not configured)
device blacklist   = (not configured)
wwan blacklist     = enabled

Bus 001 Device 002 ID 8087:8000 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp.  (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 002 ID 064e:9301 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Suyin Corp.  (uvcvideo)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
```

+++ Battery Status

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = Hewlett-Packard
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = Primary
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design             =   1984 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full                    =   1984 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now                     =   1984 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/current_now                    =      0 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Full
```

Answer (score 0):

Thermald?  This is intended to keep the computer cool... it defaults to using skin temperature sensor (which mine didn't have, so I set it to look at CPU temp sensor instead).  You feed it a value and it tries to keep it at or below that temperature (more or less, it can overshoot a couple degrees if it's heating up fast.)

If you're HP has fan control, this'll probalby just ramp up the fan and use more power.  But if it doens't have fan control (or you can disable thermald's use of fan control), it uses CPU power save modes and throttling, VERY effectively.

I had a Dell or two where I could find a sweet spot with this software that'd cool them by like 20-30 celsius (at the CPU, but the case cooled off a lot too).  If I ran CPUBurn, it'd run at like 50-60% speed... but if I ran anything else that used the CPU 100%, it'd run at 90-100% speed (and anything below 100% CPU usage would run at 100% speed).  I was using this one plugged in (just wanted it to run cooler), but that has to translate to some battery power savings.